# Add random datetimes to timestamps

Tags: pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a column of `timestamps` that span over 24 hours. I want to convert these to differentiate between days. I've done this by converting to `timedelta`. The result is displayed below.

The question I have is, can these be converted or re-arranged again to provide random `datetimes`. e.g. `dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['8:00','18:00','28:00'],                                      
    })

df['Time'] = [x + ':00' for x in df['Time']]
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

Out:

```
             Time
0 0 days 08:00:00
1 0 days 18:00:00
2 1 days 04:00:00
```

Intended Output:

```
             Time
0 1/01/1904  08:00:00 AM
1 1/01/1904  18:00:00 PM
2 2/01/1904  04:00:00 AM
```

The input timestamps will never go over more than 2 days. Is there a package that can achieve this or would a dummy start and end dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you convert the Time just adding the date part

```
df.Time+pd.to_datetime('1904-01-01')
0   1904-01-01 08:00:00
1   1904-01-01 18:00:00
2   1904-01-02 04:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```